# How to run a code in each worksheet starting from worksheet 4

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have created a macro that calls another macro, then to run on each worksheet from worksheet 4. The macro runs on the first worksheet (worksheet 4), but then does not run on all the other worksheets.

The initial macro which should loop through all worksheets starting from worksheet 4 is:

```
Sub DeleteLoop()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If MsgBox("Do you want to continue", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    If MsgBox("Are you sure? Have you taken a backup of your spreadsheet?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate
        For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
        Call DeleteMacro
        MsgBox "I'm currently on sheet " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Next i
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The macro to run on each worksheet is as follows:

```
Sub DeleteMacro()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Call UnProtectSheet
Range("F12").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("Paid", "Cancelled", " "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
y = Cells.Item(3, "L")
x = Cells.Item(8, "E")
    If x > 0 Then

    Application.Goto Reference:="R12C1"
    Call NextVisibleRow

    If y > 1 Then
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    End If

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Application.Goto Reference:="R12C1"
Call NextVisibleRow
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

If ActiveCell.Value = "Balance" Then
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End If

Call NextVisibleRow
Call ProtectSheet
End Sub
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong which is preventing the macro from running on each worksheet from worksheet 4 to the last worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the sheet on which sheet the macro is working. Adding `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate` directly above your call to `DeleteMacro` should do the trick.

Note that using `Select` and `Activate` is bad practice. It's inefficient and easily leads to bugs like this one. You should consider reading up on how to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 0):

You are only running the For statement over and over again, without ever changing the active worksheet.  Adding the Worksheets(i).Activate after For... Should fix that.